# Facebook android sdk not clear previous login at logout

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

My app has facebook login integration in it, And i found one issue while re-login, When i tried to logout from facebook  and after that re-login i am getting previous user auto login in my app but what i need is to login as new user. Don't Know what's Going wrong

My Logout code is

```
val parameters = Bundle()

    val request = GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/permissions/",
            parameters,
            HttpMethod.DELETE,
            GraphRequest.Callback {
                // Insert your code here
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
            })

    request.executeAsync()
```

Comment: Hello Jack , check my answer below

Comment: The code is ok but problem is in menifest, mistakenly i have registered com.facebook.CustomTabActivity which causing this error

Comment: Can you accept my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to initialize the FacebookSdk in the logout activity before calling logOut().**

`LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();`,will work

**but dont forgot to put** `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` *inside your LogoutActivity onCreate*

Answer (score 0):

For **Logout** from **Facebook** only need to use:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Comment: he is already doing that , but he is missing to initialize it

Comment: but it is in method... doesn't need to use method

Comment: You need to initialize the FacebookSdk in the logout activity before calling logOut().

Comment: Even though I initialise it, my app remembers the previous sign in, So, It keeps showing up 'Are you gonna continue?' and If I cancel, it goes back to the previous screen. So, I can't sign in with other accounts... How can I solve this?

Comment: @c-an were you able to solve it? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: As far as I know, we can't solve it because users login here and there and the services are all connected(I don't know how it works  under the hood). For example, once you login facebook on Chrome, Facebook app or other apps that use facebook login will know that you singed in. I found that other social networks works the same. @Atheer

Comment: @c-an thank you for your reply, yeah it's pretty complicated. right now I have to go to google chrome and log out, then come back to my app.

Answer (score 0):

In facebook SDK,if you want to completely de-couple, make sure you also remove the app from the user's facebook account. This method disconnects the user completely:

```
public void logoutFromFacebook() {

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
        return; // user already logged out
    }

    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
            .Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {    
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

        }
    }).executeAsync();
}
```

also use this `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` to initialize the facebook sdk.

Hope it will help you!!